# maven build error : No plugin found for prefix 'system' in the current project

Tags: maven

Running the command `mvn -v`, it's ok. But runing command `mvn system:help`:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/153M
......
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'system' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository), nexus (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException:
```

Why had a prefix 'system'? How to do?

Comment: Please post your POM.

Comment: thanks，I made a mistake，the right command is 'mvn help:system'.